# PHP Splice into next iteration of loop

Tags: php, loops

I would like to add to the next iteration of a loop. For example, if the $value is 3, splice a new value for the next loop while maintaining the remainder of the array.

```
$array=[1,2,3,4,5];
foreach($array as $key=>&$value){
 if($value===3){array_splice($array,$key,0,'test');}
 echo $value;
}
// 1,2,3,5
```

I would like the output to be:

```
// 1,2,3,'test',4,5
```

This is a simplified example.

Comment: if($value===3){array_splice($array,0,$value,'test');}
try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably more easily done using [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the key of the value that you want to add the element after:

```
$array=[1,2,3,4,5];
if (($k = array_search(3, $array)) !== false) {
    array_splice($array, $k+1, 0, array('test'));
}
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => test
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BlWGR)

Comment: Thanks for the great solution! I also found a different solution below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$array=[1,2,3,4,5];
foreach($array as $key=>&$value){
 if($value===3){$array=array_merge(['test'],array_slice($array,$key+1));}
 echo $value;
}
```